# Perfect square for n in N

Tags: number-theory

a and b in N ,
Such a.2^n+b is a perfect square for every n in N.

```
    Prove that a=0
```

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: What have you tried?  How about thinking about what happens for small values of $n$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $n\in \Bbb N$. We are given that there are natural numbers $u, v, w$ with $u^2=2^na+b$, $v^2=2^{n+1}a+b$,  and $w^2=2^{n+2}a+b$. 
There are two cases.

1. Assume $b=0$. Then $v^2=2u^2$, which is only possible for $v=u=0$ because $\sqrt 2$ is irrational. Hence $a=0$ as desired.
2. Assume $b\ne 0$. Then $3b=4u^2-w^2$ and so $2u\pm w\ne 0$. More precisely,
   $$m:=\left|2u-w\right|=\left|\frac{4u^2-w^2}{2u+w}\right|=\left|\frac{3b}{2u+w}\right|$$
   is a positive integer. Hence $m\ge 1$. It follows that $2u+w= \frac{3b}m\le 3b$ and from this, $$ 2^na+b=u^2\le 9b^2.$$As this holds for all $n$, we conlcude $a=0$.